# Cucumber 4 - Is there any alternate for Reporter Interface for Custom Report?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Currently I am using Cucumber Options with plugin to invoke Custom Report Class implements Reporter. How to do it in newer Cucumber 4 version. Mainly to get Test Results to build own custom reports.

Comment: Could you please show your code. Posting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `Formatter` interface - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/formatter/Formatter.java.

Though this is planned for removal. - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1401

Better off using the `Plugin` - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/Plugin.java plus `EventListener` - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/event/EventListener.java

Also look at ConcurrentEventListener https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/event/ConcurrentEventListener.java if u plan to use parallel running - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/1357

Comment: Thanks for the detailed Inputs. Helps a lot. Started implementing Plugin. Hope it wouldn't be removed